# cache memory capacity and words in cache memory

Tags: cache, capacity

Each block of the set associative **cache memory has capacity of 4 words of 16-bits**, one section has 2 blocks. Whole **cache memory has 4096 words**.

I do not understand the differences between these bold ones. Aren't they the same?

Comment: I'm sure you are missing a whole sentence or paragraph, but it tells you the cache size is 4096 words broken into blocks of 4 works. That's 1024 blocks. Those are further divided into sections with one section 2 blocks in size. After that you need more information.

Comment: The professor gave just this information for question. But thank you. @Trevor

Answer (score 1):

No, it says each BLOCK has 4 words, and each word has 16 bits. Thus a block has 64 bits. Then it says, a SECTION has 2 blocks i.e 8 words, or 128 bits. The whole cache is 4’096 words, which would be 512 sections or equivalently 1’024 blocks, or 65’536 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you are missing a whole sentence or paragraph, but it tells you the cache size is 4096 words broken into blocks of 4 works. That's 1024 blocks. Those are further divided into sections with one section 2 blocks in size.

After that you need more information.